# static variables in arm when using -fpic and -msingle-pic-base

Tags: static, arm, cortex-m, fpic

When compiling for arm cortex-m3 with options -fpic and -msingle-pic-base it creates a global offset table, However static variables, global or local, are not included in the global offset table, and have absolute addresses. is this a bug or a feature, or am I missing an extra option?

Comment: See this [GOT answer by **R**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688076/process-linkage-table-and-global-offset-table).  The *key concept* is **shared libraries**.  You can create an executable with `-fpic` and it is still not a *shared library*; there is no reason for the compiler to emit anything to the **GOT**.