# Difference between GOT and GOTOFF

Tags: assembly, x86, dynamic-linking, got

I'm a beginner to 32 bit assembly and I tried to compile a simple C program into Assembly. I understand most of it except when it uses GOTOFF.

```
    .file   "main.c"
    .text
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "Hello world"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    leal    4(%esp), %ecx
    .cfi_def_cfa 1, 0
    andl    $-16, %esp
    pushl   -4(%ecx)
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_escape 0x10,0x5,0x2,0x75,0
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    pushl   %ebx
    pushl   %ecx
    .cfi_escape 0xf,0x3,0x75,0x78,0x6
    .cfi_escape 0x10,0x3,0x2,0x75,0x7c
    call    __x86.get_pc_thunk.ax
    addl    $_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_, %eax
    subl    $12, %esp
    leal    .LC0@GOTOFF(%eax), %edx     # <- Here
    pushl   %edx
    movl    %eax, %ebx
    call    puts@PLT
    addl    $16, %esp
    movl    $0, %eax
    leal    -8(%ebp), %esp
    popl    %ecx
    .cfi_restore 1
    .cfi_def_cfa 1, 0
    popl    %ebx
    .cfi_restore 3
    popl    %ebp
    .cfi_restore 5
    leal    -4(%ecx), %esp
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .section    .text.__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax,"axG",@progbits,__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax,comdat
    .globl  __x86.get_pc_thunk.ax
    .hidden __x86.get_pc_thunk.ax
    .type   __x86.get_pc_thunk.ax, @function
__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    (%esp), %eax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 9.2.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Why does it use GOTOFF? Isn't the address of GOT already loaded in %eax? What is the difference between GOT and GOTOFF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**symbol@GOTOFF addresses the variable itself, relative to the GOT base (as a convenient but arbitrary choice of anchor)**.  `lea` of that gives you symbol address, `mov` would give you data at the symbol.  (The first few bytes of the string in this case.)

symbol@GOT gives you offset (within the GOT) of the GOT entry, for that symbol.  A `mov` load from there gives you the address of the symbol.  (GOT entries are filled in by the dynamic linker).

[Why use the Global Offset Table for symbols defined in the shared library itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55587313/why-use-the-global-offset-table-for-symbols-defined-in-the-shared-library-itself) has an example of accessing an `extern` variable that does result in getting its address from the GOT and then dereferencing that.

---

BTW, this is position-independent code.  Your GCC is configured that way by default.  If you used `-fno-pie -no-pie` to make a traditional position-*dependent* executable, you'd just get a normal efficient `pushl $.LC0`.  (32-bit is missing RIP-relative addressing so it's quite inefficient.)

In a non-PIE (or in 64-bit PIE), the GOT barely gets used at all.  The main executable defines space for symbols so it can access them without going through the GOT.  libc code uses the GOT anyway (mostly because of symbol interposition in 64-bit code) so letting the main executable provide the symbol doesn't cost anything and makes the non-PIE executable faster.

We can get a non-PIE executable to use the GOT directly for shared library function addresses with `-fno-plt`, instead of calling into the PLT and having it use the GOT.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void foo() { putchar('\n'); }
```

[gcc9.2 `-O3 -m32 -fno-plt` on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%0Avoid+foo()+%7B%0A++++putchar(!'%5Cn!')%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aextern+int+var%3B%0Aint+*getaddr(void)+%7B+return+%26var%3B+%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:42.093417937473426,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:boost,ver:'171')),options:'-O3+-m32+-fno-plt',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:49.88145882393966,l:'4',m:49.36634085313496,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:boost,ver:'171')),options:'-O3+-m32',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50.63365914686504,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:57.90658206252661,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)  (`-fno-pie` is the default on the Godbolt compiler explorer, unlike your system.)

```
foo():
        sub     esp, 20                  # gcc loves to waste an extra 16 bytes of stack 
        push    DWORD PTR stdout         # [disp32] absolute address
        push    10
        call    [DWORD PTR _IO_putc@GOT]
        add     esp, 28
        ret
```

Both `push` and `call` have a memory operand using a 32-bit absolute address. `push` is loading the `FILE*` value of `stdout` from a known (link-time-constant) address.  (There isn't a text relocation for it.)

`call` is loading the function pointer saved by the dynamic linker from the GOT.  (And loading it directly into EIP.)

Comment: So GOTOFF contains the offset from the GOT?

Comment: @taxydtails: It's syntax that tells the assembler + linker to fill in that offset when linking.  It's not a location so it can't "contain" anything.  (Or perhaps you mean the `disp32` in the addressing mode.  Yes *that* will contain the symbol's offset from the GOT after linking.)

Comment: @PeterSmith sorry for asking this again. So GOTOFF is not a section, but just a way to tell the assembler + linker to replace that with an offset?

Comment: @taxydtails: yes, you can see that from how GCC uses it in my example, and in Ross's example in the linked answer.