# symbol relocation - extern,static and no storage class

Tags: linker, symbols, relocation

I have 3 sample codes below(all .so files):

1)

```
int myglob = 42;

int fun(int a, int b)
{
    return myglob + a + b;
}
```

2)

```
static int myglob = 42;

int fun(int a, int b)
{
    return myglob + a + b;
}
```

3)

```
extern int myglob;

int fun(int a, int b)
{
    return myglob + a + b;
}
```

How do relocations work in these three cases? How are they different from each other?

---

**My guesses** :

Since `myglob` in the 3rd case is `extern`, it uses the `GOT` table.

In the 2nd case, I don't think we need to use the GOT table since `myglob` is defined in the object itself and linker knows about the offset between the `.text` and `.data` sections, so we can add the known *offset* to the current instruction pointer to access `myglob` in the data section.

1st one is declared in the *file scope* and don't specify a storage class, then it defaults to *external linkage*. So this should behave similar to the 3rd case.

Am I correct?

Comment: I think your question was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688076/process-linkage-table-and-global-offset-table

Comment: Thnx for the indirection :D